# Weird error when sorting list of files by creation date in Python

Tags: python, file, sorting, date

I have been following this tutorial http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576804-find-the-oldest-or-yougest-of-a-list-of-files/ to sort a list of files into creation date.
However, when I run the script with this code:

```
import os

path = 'pages/'

files = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)

input(files)
```

...I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ilmiont_server\blog\homepage.py", line 17, in <module>
    files = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\genericpath.py", line 64, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'rsr.txt'
```

'rsr.txt' is currently the only file in the 'pages' directory I search through. The weird thing is it works in the same directory as the script and if the 'pages' directory is empty. For context, the 'pages' folder I want to sort is one level lower than the folder that the script resides in. Please help me realize what is going wrong!

Thanks in advance, Ilmiont.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`os.path.getctime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) cannot find the files returned by `os.listdir` because `os.listdir` only returns their names, not their paths.  You need to give `os.path.getctime` the paths to the files.

The below should work for your specific case:

```
import os

path = 'pages/'

files = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(path+x))

input(files)
```

However, it is usually safer to use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create file paths:

```
import os

path = 'pages/'

files = sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path, x)))

input(files)
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much indeed; I didn't know that before! Works fine now. Same for @pajton above. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to join the path with filename, cause `os.listdir()` gives you filenames and `os.path.getctime()` requires full path:

```
paths = [os.path.join(path, fname) for fname in os.listdir(path)]
files = sorted(paths, key=os.path.getctime)
```